# robot_localization : no output from navsat_transform on odometry/gps

Tags: ros, navigation, ros-kinetic, navsat-transform-node, robot-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I have a bag file which has IMU, GPS and wheel odometry and I'm trying to fuse it through robot_localization. I have followed everything as per the document. the ekf node is working fine but there is no output on the topic odometry/gps.
I am manually tuning the covariance values for all the three sensors. For this I have a small code which runs above the bag file and just adds up the values in covariance matrix.

Please find the attached launch file and config file . Also, I am pasting few messages for IMU, GOS and odometry

**IMU**:

```
 header: 
   seq: 122
   stamp: 
     secs: 1531127130
     nsecs: 412077068
   frame_id: "imu_link"
  orientation: 
    x: 0.01904296875
    y: -0.0274047851562
    z: -0.852172851562
    w: 0.522216796875
  orientation_covariance: [24.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 24.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 24.0]
  angular_velocity: 
    x: 2.375
    y: -0.875
    z: 2.75
  angular_velocity_covariance: [24.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 24.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 24.0]
  linear_acceleration: 
    x: -0.270000010729
    y: 1.48000001907
    z: -1.27999997139
  linear_acceleration_covariance: [24.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 24.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 24.0]
```

**GPS**:

```
header: 
  seq: 8
  stamp: 
    secs: 1531127123
    nsecs:  87058067
  frame_id: "gps_link"
status: 
  status: 0
  service: 1
latitude: 50.72745
longitude: 7.087071
altitude: 110.3
position_covariance: [0.01, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.01, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.01]
position_covariance_type: 1
```

**Odometry**:

```
header: 
  seq: 633
  stamp:
    secs: 1531127147
    nsecs: 190536275
  frame_id: "odom"
child_frame_id: "base_link"
pose: 
  pose: 
    position: 
      x: 8.16897660416
      y: -7.75282666754
      z: 0.0
    orientation: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: -0.6552952454
      w: 0.755372849231
  covariance: [0.375, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.375, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.375, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.375, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.375, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.375]
twist: 
  twist: 
    linear: 
      x: 0.866949711312
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
    angular: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0533507514654
  covariance: [0.01, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.01, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.01, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.01, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.01, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.01]
```

Config file:

```
# https://github.com/cra-ros-pkg/robot_localization/blob/kinetic-devel/params/dual_ekf_navsat_example.yaml

ekf_se_odom:
    frequency: 30
    sensor_timeout: 0.1
    two_d_mode: true
    
    map_frame: map
    odom_frame: odom
    base_link_frame: base_link
    world_frame: odom
    
    odom0: odometry/cov
    odom0_config: [false, false, false,    #X,Y,Z
                 false, false, true,       #roll,pitch,yaw
                 true,  true,  false,      #X˙,Y˙,Z
                 false, false, true,       #roll˙,pitch˙,yaw 
                 false, false, false]      #X¨,Y¨,Z
    odom0_differential: false
    odom0_queue_size: 10
                    
    imu0: imu/cov
    imu0_config: [false, false, false,
                false,  false,  true,
                false, false, false,
                false,  false,  true,
                true,  false,  false]
    imu0_differential: false
    imu0_queue_size: 10
    imu0_remove_gravitational_acceleration: false

    use_control: false

ekf_se_map:
    frequency: 30
    two_d_mode: true
    
    map_frame: map
    odom_frame: odom
    base_link_frame: base_link
    world_frame: map
    
    odom0: odometry/cov
    odom0_config: [false, false, false,    #X,Y,Z
                 false, false, false,       #roll,pitch,yaw
                 true,  true,  false,      #X˙,Y˙,Z
                 false, false, true,       #roll˙,pitch˙,yaw 
                 false, false, false]      #X¨,Y¨,Z
    odom0_differential: false
    odom0_queue_size: 10
    
    odom1: odometry/gps
    odom1_config: [true,  true,  false,
                 false, false, false,
                 false, false, false,
                 false, false, false,
                 false, false, false]
    odom1_differential: false
    odom1_queue_size: 10
                    
    imu0: imu/cov
    imu0_config: [false, false, false,
                false,  false,  false,
                false, false, false,
                false,  false,  false,
                false,  false,  false]
    imu0_differential: false
    imu0_queue_size: 10
    imu0_remove_gravitational_acceleration: false

    use_control: false

navsat_transform:
    frequency: 30
    delay: 3.0
    magnetic_declination_radians: 0.034732052 # For lat/long 50.727246, 7.086934
    yaw_offset: 2.35619449019 # IMU reads 0 facing magnetic north, not east
    broadcast_utm_transform: flase
    zero_altitude: true
    publish_filtered_gps: false
    use_odometry_yaw: false
    wait_for_datum: false
```

[LAUNCH FILE](https://goo.gl/tP4oQW)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/300679/robot_localization-:-no-output-from-navsat_transform-on-odometry/gps/) by [pk11](https://answers.ros.org/users/37000/pk11/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2018-08-15

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Two main comments:

1. Don't fuse yaw from your wheel odometry *and* your IMU in the `odom` EKF. Just use the data from the IMU. As you drive around, those values will diverge, and the filter will jump between them.
2. Your GPS data is in the `gps_link` frame, and your IMU data is in the `imu_link` frame, but your launch file doesn't seem to provide any transforms from `base_link`->`imu_link` or `base_link`->`gps_link`. See the "Common errors" section of the [wiki](http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/robot_localization/html/preparing_sensor_data.html#common-errors):

> Velocity data should be reported in the frame given by the base_link_frame parameter, or a transform should exist between the frame_id of the velocity data and the base_link_frame.

In this case, even though the GPS and IMU both provide some pose data, you still need to provide transforms from `base_link` to the `frame_ids` in the messages. Your odom data is already in the `odom` and `base_link` frames, so that's fine.

But my general advice is to back up and do one thing at a time. Start with just a single `odom` EKF, and only fuse the wheel encoder data. When you're satisfied that it's working, add the IMU data. Then move on to the next EKF, and repeat. Then add `navsat_transform_node`, and repeat.

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2018-08-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pk11](https://answers.ros.org/users/37000/pk11/) on 2018-10-31**:
Thanks..! that helped, there was no Tf, I just had to launch the robot description. Basic mistake..!